# Construction of some function on the group of permutations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $x=(x_1,\ldots, x_{2m})$ be vector in  $R^{2m}$ and let $r=(r_1,\ldots,r_{2m})$be sequence, such that  $P(r_i=1)=P(r_i=-1)=1/2.$ Consider the following set

$$\begin{align*}
X=\{r \in\{-1, 1\}^{2m}| \sum_{i=1}^{2m}r_i=0\}=\{r\in\{-1, 1\}^{2m}| r_i=\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
1,&\quad i\in Y\\[4mm]
-1,&\quad i \notin Y
\end{array}\right.\},
\end{align*}
$$
where $Y\subset \{1,.., 2m\}, card(Y)=m.$ For set $X$ we put into correspondence the group $S_{2m}$ of all permutations of set $\{1,..., 2m\}$ as
$$\begin{align*}
\pi(\cdot)\longrightarrow r_{\pi(i)}=\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
1,&\quad \pi(i)\leq m\\[4mm]
-1,&\quad \pi(i)> m
\end{array}\right..
\end{align*}$$

One can define $f:S_{2m}\longrightarrow R$ to be
$\begin{align}
f(\pi)=\left|\sum_{i=1}^mx_{\pi(i)}-\sum_{i=m+1}^{2m}x_{\pi(i)}\right|.
\end{align}$

Please help me to understand how the function $f(\pi)$ was constructed?

(I am confused because one element in the probability space corresponds few elements in the group of permutations--we have $2^{2m}$ elements in the probability space and $(2m)!$ elements in the group of permutations).

Thank you.

Comment: (a) We have $r_i$, depending on $\pi$ (maybe better denoted by $r_\pi(i)$), and $x_{\pi(i)}$ here. (b) The backwards arrow in the definition of $r-i$ is unwarranted. The permutation $\pi$ cannot be reconstructed from the data $r_\pi(i)$ $\,1\leq i\leq 2m)$.

Comment: Why not just start with a given $(x_1, \ldots, x_{2m})$ and define $f$ right-away by $f(\pi)=\ldots$?

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen: I wanted to understand the logic--how one define $f(\pi)$. So I've wrote whale steps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has quite unrelated parts, this makes difficult to understand what is really asked, but one part is clear, which asks:

> *(I am confused because one element in the probability space corresponds few elements in the group of permutations--we have $2^{2m}$ elements in the probability space and $(2m)!$ elements in the group of permutations).*

The confusion might be explained as follows. The sample space $X_0$ of the random sequence $r=(r_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant2m}$ is indeed $X_0=\{-1,1\}^{2m}$, which has size $2^{2m}$, but this is irrelevant for two reasons:

- First, the function $f$ uses only permutations corresponding to sequences $r$ in $X\subset X_0$, where $X$ is defined by the condition $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2m}r_k=0$. And the size of $X$ is ${2m\choose m}$, much less than the size $2^{2m}$ of $X_0$.
- Second, the correspondence $\pi\mapsto r_\pi$ from $\mathfrak S_{2m}$ to $X$ is many-to-one since $r_\pi$ only keeps track of whether $\pi(i)\leqslant m$ or not, for each $i$, and not of the exact value of $\pi(i)$. For a given $r$ in $X$, to know that $r=r_\pi$ is not sufficient to know $\pi$ since one lacks the exact value of $\pi(i)$, either in $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ or in $\{m+1,\ldots,2m\}$. There are $(m!)^2$ possible such choices hence each $r$ in $X$ corresponds to $q=(m!)^2$ permutations $\pi$ in $\mathfrak S_{2m}$.

The take-home message is as follows:

> The correspondence $\pi\mapsto r_\pi$ goes from $\mathfrak S_{2m}$ to $X$ (hence the size $2^{2m}$ of $X_0$ is irrelevant), and is $q$-to-one (and not one-to-one). 
>  As was to be expected,
>   $q\cdot|X|=|\mathfrak S_{2m}|$, since $|\mathfrak S_{2m}|=(2m)!$, $|X|={2m\choose m}$ and $q=(m!)^2$.

Nothing in the above is *probabilistic* in any way, and, in fact, the whole part of the question mentioning probability is really confusing. Maybe what the OP has in mind could be reformulated as follows.
Consider a random permutation $Q$, distributed uniformly in $\mathfrak S_{2m}$, and let 
$$
R=r_Q.
$$ 
That is, $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathrm P)$ is the underlying probability space, $Q:\Omega\to\mathfrak S_{2m}$, $R:\Omega\to X$, for every $\pi$ in $\mathfrak S_{2m}$, $\mathrm P(Q=\pi)=|\mathfrak S_{2m}|^{-1}=[(2m)!]^{-1}$, and, for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$, $R(\omega)=r_{Q(\omega)}$, where, for every $\pi$ in $\mathfrak S_{2m}$, $r_\pi$ is defined as in the post. Then:

> The random variable $R=(R_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant 2m}$ is distributed uniformly in $X$, in particular, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2m}R_k=0$ almost surely, and, for every $k$, $\mathrm P(R_k=+1)=\mathrm P(R_k=-1)=\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's meant by "how the function $f$ was constructed." It seems pretty clear how it's defined and evaluated - and it seems to have nothing to do with $X$ or probability.

You have some $x$ in ${\bf R}^{2m}$. Let's say, $m=3$, and $x=(3,1,4,1,5,9)$. Then you have some permutation $\pi$; let's say, $$\pi=\pmatrix{1&2&3&4&5&6\cr3&6&1&5&4&2\cr}$$ in the 2-row notation. Then $$f(\pi)=\left|(x_{\pi(1)}+x_{\pi(2)}+x_{\pi(3)})-(x_{\pi(4)}+x_{\pi(5)}+x_{\pi(6)})\right|=\left|(x_3+x_6+x_1)-(x_5+x_4+x_2)\right|=\left|(4+9+3)-(5+1+1)\right|$$